# Jenkins UI Textfinder how to set multiple regex

Tags: regex, user-interface, jenkins, text, finder

I'm using the Jenkins UI and I want to let the test fail if at least one of multiple regex occur in the console output. So I'm using Jenkins Text Finder in the Post-build Actions.
I want the test to fail when these expression occur: 
"Failed" and "Traceback (most recent call last)"

Any idea how to accomplish this?

Jenkins suggest to use the syntax of Java Pattern.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

But I haven't found a correct way yet to get the correct behaviour.

Grateful for any hint.

Comment: Using the Log parser with rules as solution

Answer (score 1):

Just use:

```
regex1|regex2|...|regexn
```

and you'll get a regular expression that matches any of `regex1`, `regex2`, ... `regexn`.